# Linking error in OMNeT++ using Boost serialization library

Tags: boost, omnet++

I'm very new to OMNeT++ and I'd like to use the serialization-library contained in the boost framework. However, when trying to use it, I get quite many errors such as:

```
Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()'
OmCCN line 36, external location: /home/alexander/UniBE/BT/simulator/boost-compiledLibs
/include/boost/serialization/throw_exception.hpp    C/C++ Problem
```

. I guess the problem is that I didn't yet link the compiled library in OMNeT. I've had a look at the makefile but any changes there are worthless since it is generated automatically by makemake. Furthermore, trying to access the menu item 'makemake' in project > properties > OMNeT++ IDE throws an error (The currently displayed page contains invalid values).

Can anyone give me a hint concerning what the error could cause or how to link the compiled library correctly?

Any hints are **very** appreciated!

cheers
alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should get the library files.

For example in Ubuntu you should install these two packages: libboost1.46-dev, and libboost-serialization1.46-dev. Header files will be installed in usr/include/boost and library files will be installed in usr/lib.

To link the serialization library to your program:

Right click on your project and click properties. Then go to OMNET++ > Makemake.

find the Link tab, and in the ***"Additional objects to link with: (wildcards, ..."*** section, specify the path to your serialization library (say /usr/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.a).